# NSTimer stop while taking screenshot of UiView iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, screenshot, nstimer, pause

I am taking screen shot of `UIView` while the screen is updating using `NStimer` method but `Timer` stops as i take screenshot of view

I am taking 5 to 8 screenshot frequently for capturing the updating on the view

But timer stops and cant get the Exact screenshot as required

My code:

```
 -(void)StartAnmation {

  timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2 target:self  selector:@selector(methodToAddImages) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
 [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];

}

 - (void)methodsave
{
   for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    UIImage *img=[self screenshotimageWithView:self.mainview];
    [gifimages addObject:img];
       }

}
```

// screenshot

```
- (UIImage ) screenshotimageWithView:(UIView )view
{

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);

[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
[view drawViewHierarchyInRect:view.bounds afterScreenUpdates:NO];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

NSData *miths=UIImagePNGRepresentation(img);

UIImage *imge=[UIImage imageWithData:miths];

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return imge;
}
```

Comment: Add the code of timer and taking screenshot of `UIView`

Comment: Add some code so we can understand your problem

Comment: look my update....

Comment: i am animating image by calling method using timer but image is stopping animating while i am taking screenshot ......

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're not blocking the main thread while taking the screenshots or with another expensive operation.

Comment: i have put my timer method in main thread look my update still it is same